# Wordpress with php 5.5 and zend opcache

Tags: php, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I currently updated/upgraded my php to 5.5.11 and want to use the opcache that comes with it.
I enabled the cache and added a few settings to php.ini

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131313/opcache.so
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

But is this enough? Can i use wordpress caching plugins or there is no need?
I used W3 total cache together with apc until now. 
Which wordpress caching plugin should i use now? Any other settings of opcache i should change?

Comment: With "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131313/opcache.so" in the php.ini the opcache was disabled.

Now i'm using it together with WP Fastest Cache and site loads very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opcache is transparent for WordPress (as it is to any PHP application).

However if you had been using APC for object cache (key/value store) via plugin — that function is not available in new bundled Zend cache, it *only* does opcode caching.

You would need to replace object cache with something different (APCu/Memcache/Redis/etc).